# Why is the expectation value of momentum of a particle in an infinite potential well zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, potential, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My book mentions that if you have an infinite (or even very deep) square well, a particle trapped in it will have the expectation value for momentum $p_x$ zero. How does one infer this using the uncertainty principle? Is it because we are sure that the particle is located inside the well and hence it has no uncertainty in it position?

Answer (score 1):

Not via uncertainty principle but via Ehrenfest theorem --

If the particle is stuck at the bottom of the well, that means its expected position is constant, so $\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle = 0$. Ehrenfest theorem says $
\frac{d}{dt}<x> = \frac{<p>}{m}$ so $\langle p \rangle$ must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Actually of course this is true for eigenstates (or stationary solutions) of the Schrodinger equation, and others states for which $\langle x\rangle $ is time independent. Since $\langle p\rangle$ captures the time dependence of $\langle x\rangle$ then it follows that $\langle p\rangle=0$ as well.  If you start with a wavefunction of the form
$$
\Psi(x,0)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \sqrt{2/a}&{\rm if }\quad x<a/2\\ 0&{\rm otherwise} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
then the resulting $\Psi(x,t)$ would have non-zero $\langle p\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

There is uncertainty in the position of the particle, this is taken as the width $a$ of the well.

Using the uncertainty principle, $\Delta p \Delta x \approx \hbar$ so that the momentum is uncertain by the amount $\Delta p \approx \hbar/a$.

Note that $\Delta p$ is taken to be the magnitude.

The reason that the average momentum comes out to zero because momentum is a vector quantity and the particle is as much likely to be moving to the left and the right so that the average value of momentum is zero.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the particle like a prisoner in a cell. The unfortunate prisoner can pace up and down all day and all night long but he can't escape.

Effectively his average velocity (as vector) is zero and thus also his average momentum (as a vector).

This does not mean the prisoner does not move however.